# Discord.py How to do an action depending on the user reaction

Tags: discord.py

How can I check for the user reaction? I'm using that code:

```
@client.command()
async def react(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("Test")
    await question.add_reaction("<>")
    await question.add_reaction("<>")
```

How can I do an action if the user react to the message with  and another action if the user react to the message with ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) you can find `client.wait_for()` which waits for an event to happen. The example from the documentation should help you out:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$thumb'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')
```

Comment: I made a new post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382718/discord-py-trying-to-do-an-action-depending-on-user-reaction?noredirect=1#comment106816955_60382718